# Detect multiple Input fields value change from code in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field as

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="sampleValue" >
```

In some situations i am clearing the value of input as

```
$scope.sampleValue = "";
```

Is there any way to detect the change in value of input field from code?

In this case **ng-change** is not working as the value is changing from code. I have a number of such input fields, so using multiple **$watch** is not a good solution.

Comment: why not use `$watch`? You can put all those values in single `object` any add watch to it.

Comment: You can create a wrapper component and listen to `$onChanges` of it.

Comment: Like a form?@31piy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [`$watchGroup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup) instead of multiple `$watch`:

```
var fieldList = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3'];

$scope.$watchGroup(filedList, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log(newVal[0], newVal[1], newVal[2]);
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if possible make use of rxJs and Observable value , like in below example it observe string s, in you code it can observe `$scope.sampleValue = "";`

```
  let s = "Hello World";
  Observable.of(s).subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
  });
```